# Struts2 datepicker position

Tags: jquery, struts2, jquery-ui-datepicker

Is it possible to offset the datepicker position to the right a little bit?

```
<sj:datepicker name="displayEnd" required="true"
            key="displayEnd-label" displayFormat="dd-mm-yy" timepicker="true"
            timepickerStepMinute="15" readonly="true" minDate="-30"
            onBeforeTopics="setTimeToNowIfNotSet" />
```

I could not see any place in documentation where to set the position. I would like to offset the datepicker a little bit to the right, so that it does not cover other fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in CSS, but if you have multiple datepickers on the same page it will offset them all.

```
#ui-datepicker-div {
 margin-left: a_little_bit;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if Struts2 is in anyway related to the jQuery Datepicker, but in any case you can try assigning a css class to your sj:datepicker and make adjustments there.

```
<sj:datepicker name="displayEnd" required="true" class="sjDatePicker" id="displayEnd"
            key="displayEnd-label" displayFormat="dd-mm-yy" timepicker="true"
            timepickerStepMinute="15" readonly="true" minDate="-30"
            onBeforeTopics="setTimeToNowIfNotSet" />
```

In your pages' layout CSS file:

```
.sjDatePicker
{
  /*Make your positioning adjustments here*/
}
```

Before changing anything you can try opening up your browsers' javascript console and enter the following to see if modifying the datepickers style works at all. (provided you are using jquery)

```
$('#displayEnd').css("margin-top","20px");
```

If this works, modifying the style in the CSS file should as well.

Note that your datepicker element needs to have the id "displayEnd" for this to work.

Comment: Beware this will also set margin for datepicker input field.

Comment: I was not aware of that. @Resh32 , you should try inspecting the datepicker then and see what id it has. if you're lucky, the id is static and you can style just this one datepicker.

Comment: Id is static but datepicker div is generated per page, not per field.